# height for Row at indexPath throwing EXC Bad Access error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

So I'm receiving a EXC Bad Access error when I enter the if statement below. The frustrating bit is that I've confirmed that the indexPath and tableView are pointing to the right place. Also, the exact same if statement is used elsewhere in my code in the same implementation file with no error.

Would appreciate the help.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]]-1))
    {
        return 44.0;
    } else {
        return 60.0;
    }                       
}
```

Comment: what are you trying ? what is your condition for 44.0 and 60.0 row height ?

Comment: I'm trying to make the row height for the last item in a section 44pts tall, but I want to keep all the other row heights at 60pts tall. Therefore, if the [indexPath row] is the same as the number of rows in that section, then it's the last one and I should return the unique row height. This might not be the best way to solve this problem. But at this point, I've spent so much time trying to identify the root cause of this bug that I still want to tease it out.

Comment: Show us the exception stack trace.

Comment: @HotLicks This question is from 2012...

Comment: @erdekhayser - #*&% zombies!!

Comment: you are calling numberOfRowsInSection method infinitely by this adding this line to your code -> [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]]

Answer (score 0):

```
if([indexPath row] == ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]-1]))
    {
        return 44.0;
    } else {
        return 60.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your logic `[indexPath section]-1` the number of rows in first section that is 0th section should be -1

Comment: The intent of the "-1" was to match up cardinal vs nominal numbers.

Comment: So, I meant to match up the row which would appear as 0 or 1 to the number of rows in the section which would be 1 or 2. Is that logic correct?

Comment: here the section might have any number of rows depending upon what you have defined...this is not some general logic as it pertains to the way you have defined number of sections and rows in tableview..

Answer (score 0):

**`[indexPath section]-1` for section with index "0" is giving you bad access.** Remove -1 from this statement.

Comment: This is wrong. The op is subtracting 1 from the number of rows in a section not from the section index. Notice the punctuation.

Comment: in your statement you first take number of section from you indexPath and after that you subtracting 1 from that value. And after all that you are trying to get the row with index `[indexPath section]-1` that will be `-1` for the case of `section = 0`.

Comment: No, I've tested this by putting the log statement: NSLog(@"numRowsInSction = %d",([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]]-1)); in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and it correctly logs 1 minus the number of rows in the section I clicked in. If you are correct it should give me an error if I click in section 0.  In any case, taking out the -1 doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to solve your requirement is not to ask the tableview how many rows are in a section, in stead ask your datasource how many rows there are.

So for instance if your datasource is an array, check array.count (of course you have some other datasource since you have sections, but you get the point)

Comment: Good point! So I was asking the view for data, and the view turned back around and asked the controller, who turned and asked the datasource, but I could have gone straight to the datasource. I wonder if that is why I was getting such odd errors.

Comment: Hope this will solve your problems. Personally I find it a bad practice to call the UITableViewDelegate methods yourself, it can get you in serious trouble ;)

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is an old question, but it might be helpful to others in the future.*

**Solution:**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger numOfRowsInSection = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    if (indexPath.row == (numOfRowsInSection - 1))
        return 44.0;
    else
        return 60.0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

What's happening is for every `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]]` call the system is calling `[tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` again creating an infinite loop and eventually the app is crashing.

Use `dataSource` property of `tableView` to prevent the loop, like this:

```
[tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using a tableView Delegate method. Try this instead:

```
 if([indexPath row] == ([self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1))
```